# Problems using etree in Python scraper

Tags: python, screen-scraping, lxml

I'm a newbie in Python looking to build a screen scraper in Scraperwiki but I'm struggling with an error I can't work out how to fix. 
Essentially, I want to parse an xml file but can't work out how to have my  gp_indicators_scrape function access the getroot() method.

Can anyone fix it, and more importantly, point me towards an explanation so I can avoid the problem in future?

Here's the scraper: https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/choiceshu1

The key bits of code:

```
import lxml.html
import urlparse
from urlparse import urlparse
from lxml.etree import etree

def gp_indicators_scrape(org_URL):

     indicator_xml = etree.parse(org_URL)
     root = lxml.etree.getroot(indicator_XML)
     print root 

html = scraperwiki.scrape(combined_URL_for_first_scrape)
print html
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
links = root.cssselect("dd a")
```

And here's the error when it runs

```
Line 5 - from lxml.etree import etree
ImportError: cannot import name etree
```

Comment: You don't have a file called lxml.py in your PYTHONPATH? And why is the error on line 5 and the import in your code sample on line 4?

Comment: Varela, I've done that. Now I get a "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getroot'" error...

Comment: where did you get this code? There are bunch of errors. You need to call getroot on indicator_xml. indicator_XML would be unknown variable it's not the same as indicator_xml

Comment: I admit's a bit hacked together with my limited knowledge, cutting and pasting and lack of coding discipline. Please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from lxml.etree import etree` should be `from lxml import etree`

Also, just noticed - `lxml.etree.getroot(...)` - you can drop the `lxml.` if you use the import above, and normally you call `getroot()` on the object returned via `etree.parse` (or similar).

NB: I haven't looked at code in the provided link...